# Is there a cleaner way to get a hold of an ActiveRecord query interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have this which works, but I thought there might be a specific method for it.

```
  @deals = Deal.where("1=1")
  if @dealFilter.min.to_i > 0
    @deals = @deals.where("size >= ?", @dealFilter.min)
  end
  if ...
```

I tried `Deal.select` but it required parameters. I found `Deal.none` but that returns none always. I tried `Deal.where` but it gave ``` undefined method ``where' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x0000001d2bfb20> ``` when I tried to chain another `where` on.

I have many conditions chained together. If no conditions match, it should return `Deal.all`.

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of ActiveRecord scopes, and move the logic into your model. For example:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :filter_min, ->(min) {
    where("size >= ?", min) if min.to_i > 0
  }
  scope :filter_max, ->(max) {
    where("size <= ?", max) if max.to_i > 0
  }

end
```

And then in your controller you can write:

```
Deal.filter_min(@dealFilter.min).filter_max(@dealFilter.max)
```